# Practicality of Root on ZFS

Tags: linux, virtualization, storage, freebsd, zfs

I'm preparing to install a fresh OS on my desktop machine. Its basic specs are i7 3770S with 16GB Non-ECC RAM, which is the maximum that this board supports. I actually have XenServer on there now, but with them removing features from the latest free edition, I've decided to migrate to KVM which seems to better support workarounds for passing through consumer GPUs anyway (particularly nVidia), though I can confirm that my Radeon RX580 just fine this way, as did my Radeon 7970. The board is a Gigabyte GA-H77N-WIFI for what it's worth. I remember I couldn't find information on support for PCI passthrough using VT-d or if it would support arbitrary mini-PCIe cards but for anyone out there who's searching I can confirm that both work just fine on my board (purchased Dec 14 2012).

I believe I understand the risks with Non-ECC RAM, and this machine is not really a server per se, more of a personal workstation that I'll be running VMs on. My understanding is that Non-ECC ZFS is not really any more risky than on any other filesystem and the ZFS checksumming should still be beneficial.

I'm planning to use Alpine Linux as my host operating system and virtualize most everything from there. The reason for this is KVM, which seems like the most mature, active, and widely used free virtualization host. I could be wrong and it's just not as easy to find information, but Bhyve on FreeBSD does not seem to be anywhere near as mature as KVM. I also really like what the Intel GVT-g project is trying to develop, and it also seems to best support KVM.

Alpine Linux supports root on ZFS. I use ZFS on FreeBSD (NAS4Free) and really like it. However, on that setup the root is actually on a USB drive and loaded into RAM on boot.

I would really like to know the practicality of root on ZFS. Especially on Linux where it's not a 'first class citizen' so to speak. Searching for concerns about practicality Google, all I was able to find were guides on host to do it.

Right now I'm leaning towards a setup similar to the NAS4Free embedded option, which would be to setup a really lean KVM host on Alpine and load it to a RAM disk on boot. I then would probably set up a data store either using ZFS on Linux or possibly a FreeBSD VM with a SATA card passed through. Most likely the former though because I can't fit another PCI card in the case and even though I've tested my mini PCIe SATA controller and it works and didn't seem to have issues when I briefly tested it a couple months back. I guess I just don't really trust its ASMedia 106x chipset, particularly since it says version 0.61 on the POST screen. The config would be 2x128GB SSD in a mirror vdev if used for root.

I've also read a few horror stories about low memory causing ZFS instability leading to a crash that takes the pool with it. However, my opinion is that there is a ton of FUD on the internet about ZFS, likely stemming from Sun's documentation on ZFS being geared towards an enterprise use case. It also seems to be much more important in RAIDZ setups, particularly with high capacities. I also don't believe I came across a first hand account of it happening to someone, just "I know a guy who knows a guy" stuff.

I guess the main questions are:

- Is is there really any benefit to Root on ZFS? Particularly if you're someone who doesn't put data and root on the same partition anyway?
- I like the idea of ZFS using up whatever RAM isn't used to speed up I/O, but 16GB is already pretty stretched running a VM or two. Does ZFS do a better job making use of free memory than what Linux does with its own filesystem caching anyway?

I think synthesizing my thoughts to write this all out has me leaning even more towards a lean root loaded into a RAM disk. This is all about learning though, and like I said, there seem to be a lot of conflicting opinions on ZFS. Honestly, I'm not sure I see a practical use for root on ZFS at all? Especially on Linux. Is it "just a because I can thing"? There's nothing wrong with that of course and it's hugely beneficial in making breakthroughs, just not for my workstation.